# How to resolve gcc compiler optimization-induced segmentation fault on centos dual compiler set up

Tags: c++, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have a large C++ software project build with gcc.  After adding some new code into the repository, one of the binary started to get Segmentation Fault on larger test data (no segfault on a few smaller test inputs).  I have tested on several different hardwares with two different systems.  Ubuntu 18 and Centos6.  GCC compiler tested are 6.3, 7.4 and 9.2.  Binary build on Ubuntu always good and on Centos is always bad (segfault). The OS giving trouble:

```
uname -a
Linux hostname 3.10.0-957.27.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jul 29 17:46:05 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

My Unbuntu has single compiler, but the Cenos usually has a old gcc 4.8, and on top of that we build 6.3, 7.4, or 9.2.  My C++ code was build with various versions gcc and on different harwares, all got segfault at

```
std::ostream& operator(ostream&, const string&);
```

but from one of several random places in my code.  I used the -O2 or -O3 option. When using -O0 option the binary has no problem but a few times slower.  I am trying to generate production code which needs to be faster.

I know one solution is to find out which line of code is causing this segmentation fault, which I will try next.  My question is that is there any option while making the gcc compiler that may help to resolve this segfault issue?

I have followed suggestion (provide in the comment section below) turning on full warning and updated all dependent libraries with warning message too (include boost). It looks this solved the problem. I learn a big lesson: any code we write has to pass pedantic Wall. Someone should write an answer to help other programmers.

Comment: Impossible to guess the reason from what you posted, but *I* suspect [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) somewhere in your code.

Comment: This sounds like either a compiler bug or UB in the code base.

Comment: Code that only crashes when compiled with optimizations often indicates a problem with undefined behavior (you've done something outside the C++ standard, and the optimizer does something awful with it, because as soon as undefined behavior is encountered, the compiler can do whatever it wants). As a first step, I'd suggest turning compiler warnings up to the max (`-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wpedantic` and an appropriate `-std=` flag) and resolving them whereever possible.

Comment: Have you tried `asan` and/or `ubsan`? The sanitizers are quite good at spotting problems.

Comment: `So it is very unlikely due to undefined behavior of the code` - No. It is very very _very_ likely you have undefined behavior in your code. You have to show an [MCVE] for others to help you.

Comment: KamilCuk, you are right.  While editing those undefined behavior I made one mistake and cause somewhere else to trigger a segfault. After my initial test with smaller data, the segfault is gone.  I will edit the question and do more testing. Thanks for all of the very precious suggestions above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No one else has answered this question.  I will summarize my experience here without any particular concrete codes.  First, I tested on centos6, where the original gcc was 4.8, and I built the latest gcc 9.2 compiler from gcc7.4.  On this machine binaries build with compiler 9.2 only has segmentation fault when using -O options.  The segfault is always in std ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const string&).  After I went through all my code and all the library used by my code and removed all warnings whatsoever, the segmentation fault was gone. I tested on about one hundreds input files and all finished the program with exit status 0. Strangely enough, the segmentation fault only occurs on my cento6 system initially.  My Ubuntu18 works fine even before removing all compiler warning messages and with the -O1-3 options.

I did some minor updates on my code recently, now I started to see the same segmentation fault ONLY on my Ubuntu18 (with compiler gcc 7.4).  Optimization -g O1, O1, O2, O3 all gave segmentation fault.  -g O0 produced code without any problems.  Now the Centos6 is fine with any optimization.

Since the segmentation fault location is inside standard lib, debug run does not reveal any useful information as to where is the cause of the error.  The only solution left is to comment out different chunk of code to locate which piece of code causes the segmentation fault. This prove to be useful.

After reading the 4 lines of code that caused the segmentation fault. I immediately realized which line had caused the trouble:

```
// samearray is array<int,4> somearray;
somearray[4]=someNumber;
```

So the take home message is when segmentation fault is trying to misguide you into thinking about "compiler optimizations", "different Operating systems", "different compiler versions", resist the temptation and sit down to digest your own code by commenting chunks at a time. I still don't know why the revelation of the segmentation fault is connected to compiler optimization option. Hope my suffering can help others.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to add your experiance here, I had noticed some really weird issues with inconsistent segmentation errors depending on the compiler version, but I suppose I should also check my own code just in case of an underlying issue.